buildConfig fails with "error: build error: no FROM image in Dockerfile"
I'm new to Openshift and trying to build a simple docker image within OpenShift using buildConfig with inline Dockerfile. Here is the snippet from the buildConfig:
spec:
  serviceAccount: builder
  source:
    type: Dockerfile
    dockerfile: |
      FROM ubuntu:latest
      RUN apt-get update
  strategy:
    type: Docker
    dockerStrategy:
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: hub.docker.com

When I run the build it can't find the FROM statement:
time="2024-10-31T17:06:20Z" level=info msg="Not using nati... images: kernel has    CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS_REDIRECT_DIR enabled"
I1031 17:06:20.220349       1 defaults.go:112] Defaulting ...orage driver "overlay" with options [mountopt=metacopy=on].
Caching blobs under "/var/cache/blobs".
**error: build error: no FROM image in Dockerfile**

I'm running Openshift standalone on my M3 Mac that is running Sequoia 15.1, although I doubt that has anything to do.
CRC version: 2.43.0+268795
OpenShift version: 4.17.1
MicroShift version: 4.17.1, but I doubt that is the issue. 

What am I doing wrong? I can include more of the buildConfig if needed.
Thanks

I tried using >- instead of | thinking maybe an OpenShift version change did it
I ran the file through yamllint as per larsks's answer in Creating Openshift BuildConfig with inline Dockerfile definition and it was clean.

